# update state when navigation is already in focus

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm using `createBottomTabNavigator` of react-native. Where i need to update the count when `AsyncStorage` value get updated. Below is my code -

```js
function BottomTabs({ navigation }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const checkCount = async () => {
    const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@item_id');
    const parsed = JSON.parse(item)
    if (item !== null) {
      const value = parsed.length;
      setCount(value)
    } else {
      setCount(0)
    }

  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      checkCount()

    })
    return unsubscribe;

  }, [navigation])
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>

      <Tab.Screen name="My Cart" component={MyCartScreen} options={{
        tabBarBadge: count,
        tabBarBadgeStyle: { backgroundColor: '#1ABC9D', color: 'white', fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'JosefinSlab-SemiBold', }
      }} />

    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The above code is working fine. But the problem occurs when i navigate to My Cart Screen and delete some product that time the badge count wont update. I assume this problem is because I'm using `focus` in useEffect and the component is already in focus when delete product hit that's why it won't re-render. Is there any alternative in React-native to achieve this rather using `focus` or is there another to achieve this ??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should describe `focus` event think more clearly...

Answer (score 2):

You should hoist the count state outside and pass it to BottomTabs as props. And it has nothing to do with the focus event. I think in your app you want to update the badge number every time the product count changes. Below is some code. Usually, I will achieve this using redux something like. But here just use an event bus mode. Hope this is helpful to you.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, DeviceEventEmitter, AsyncStorage, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

function Feed() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Feed!</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    width: 200,
                    height: 50,
                    backgroundColor: "green"
                }}
                onPress={
                    () => {
                        DeviceEventEmitter.emit("ADD_COUNT")
                    }
                }
            >
                <Text>add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

function Profile() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Profile!</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

function Notifications() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Notifications!</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    width: 200,
                    height: 50,
                    backgroundColor: "green"
                }}
                onPress={
                    () => {
                        DeviceEventEmitter.emit("REDUCE_COUNT")
                    }
                }
            >
                <Text>reduce</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs({ count }) {

    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Feed"
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Feed"
                component={Feed}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
                    ),
                    tabBarBadge: count
                }}
                listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    tabPress: e => {
                        //ga记录
                        DeviceEventEmitter.emit("ADD_COUNT")
                    },
                })}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Notifications"
                component={Notifications}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={size} />
                    ),
                }}
                listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    tabPress: e => {
                        //ga记录
                        // onTap();
                        DeviceEventEmitter.emit("REDUCE_COUNT")
                    },
                })}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={Profile}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("count").then(_count => {
            setCount(parseInt(_count ?? 0));
        })
    }, [])

    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("ADD_COUNT", () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
        AsyncStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(count + 1))
    })

    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("REDUCE_COUNT", () => {
        setCount(count - 1)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("count", JSON.stringify(count - 1))
    })

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MyTabs count={count} />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll try this and update you.